# Getting 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family table does not exist in region hbase:meta'

Tags: hive, hbase

I'm trying to integrate hive and hbase, but when i create (external) table in hive with hbase handler:

```
create external table entity_hbase(id bigint, value string, ts bigint, entity_type tinyint)
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
 with serdeproperties ('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,f1:value,f1:timestamp,f1:entity_type')
 tblproperties('hbase.table.name'='entity');
```

i get this error:

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException:
>   Column family table does not exist in region hbase:meta

First of all, i don't understand why error says that column family `table` (not `f1`) does not exist. Even if i create table in hbase and then try to create external table in hive i will get the same error.

Before all of this, my steps were:
1. start dfs
2. start yarn
3. start metastore db for hive
4. start metastore service 
5. start hbase
6. using hive shell try to create table with hbase handler

hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/metastore</value>
</property> 
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>postgres</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value></value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/Users/home/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://0.0.0.0:9083</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/Users/home/hbase/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.1/hdfs/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:8021</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Hadoop version: 3.1.1
Hive version: 3.1.1
Hbase version: 1.2.9